# Python Enterprise Integration Patterns Library/Framework

Tags: python, enterprise-integration

Is there a a Python library that implements the enterprise integration patterns in the classic [Enterprise Integration Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Integration_Patterns) book?

Comment: Apache camel with jython? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about [PyPipeline](http://pypipeline-esb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

> PyPipeline is an Enterprise Service Bus for Python. It is inspired from the Apache Camel project for Java. Like Camel, PyPipeline provides an intuitive Domain Specific Language to build a pipeline.